# I am trying to recursively sum integers input by the user

Tags: recursion, scheme

I am brand spanking new to scheme.  To the extent that tonight is the first time I've ever played around with it aside from what a powerpoint slide explained to me in class.  I have to write a scheme program that takes a user input operator and then performs that operation on the numbers that follow it.  (in other words implement my own version of schemes built-in '+', '*', etc operators).  The catch is that I have to use recursion.  Trying to maneuver my way around this scheme syntax is making it very difficult for me to even figure out where to start.

So, I decided to start with some code that at least recursively sums up values entered by the user (without worrying about recognizing the user inputting an operator and parentheses).  I just plain can't figure out how to make it work.  Here's what I'm trying:

```
(define run (lambda (x)
(cond
  ((eqv? x "a") (display x) )
  (else (+ x (run(read))))
 )))

(run (read))
```

The condition to check if x equals "a" was intended to be a way for me to break the recursion right now.  In the final version, the input will be in between a set of parenthesis, but I thought I'd cross that bridge when I come to it.  Anyways, the code just keeps accepting input, and never stops.  So, the condition to display x is never getting called I guess.  I know I'm probably doing everything wrong, and I would really appreciate some pointers.

EDIT:  OK, I'm at least starting to realize that something isn't making sense.  Such as my displaying x won't actually give the sum since I'm not storing the sum in x in any way.  However, I still don't understand why the code isn't at least stopping when I enter the letter a.

EDIT 2:  I've got it to work but only when the condition is equal to 1.  How can I get it to recognize an input of a char or better yet a right parenthesis to get it to end the recursion just like it is with the 1? :

```
(define run (lambda (x)
(cond
  ((eq? x 1) 0)  
 (else (+ x (run(read))))
 )))

(run (read))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

End-Of-File (EOF) marks the end of input.  Scheme has a procedure `eof-object?` for this.  Your code is basically correct:

```
(define (run x)
  (if (eof-object? x)
      0
      (+ x (run (read)))))
```

You end the run using `Control-D`.  If for some reason you don't have access to `eof-object?` just use a special character like `X`.  In that case your test would be `(eq? x #\X)`

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (addition-loop)
 (let ((answer (read)))
      (if (number? answer)
          (+ answer (addition-loop))
          0)))
```

This will break as soon as you enter something that isn't a number.

In addition as you can see, you can have a function of zero arguments.

Anyways the problem with your code is when you enter a into read, it's value it actually the same a 'a or (quote a), rather than "a".

```
(eqv? 'a "a")

;Value: #f
```